# Using xpath inside node not getting the value, but does using document

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I am stuck in a situation where i have a list of nodes and i need to get the value from the node using `xpath`.

Here is what i am trying...

```
<book>

  <book1>
     <abc><fm>text</fm></abc>
     <def></def>
     <ghi></ghi>
  </book1>
  <book2>
     <abc><fm>text</fm></abc>
     <def></def>
     <ghi></ghi>
   </book2>
   <bookN>
     <abc><fm>text</fm></abc>
     <def></def>
     <ghi></ghi>
   </bookN>
</book>
```

So here i am getting list of nodes from document and using node i am evaluating the XPATH

```
String nodeValue = (String) xPathFac
                                .compile("//fm/text()")
                                .evaluate(bookNode, XPathConstants.STRING);
```

Returns me empty string here, someone help me here please :)

**I tried .//fm/text() too but no use**

Comment: You don't have a closing `</book>` tag

Comment: @tgdavies that was typpo

Comment: I used your content, your XPATH and your Java code, it returns _"text"_ correctly. Could you provide the code where `bookNode` is generated?

Answer (score 0):

Since you have distinct nodes i.e. book1, book2, book3 and so on you need to create disti
    /book1/abc/fm
    /book2/abc/fm
    /book3/abc/fm

XPath does support regex. Hope this helps.

```
/[substring(name(), 4) = 'book']/abc/fm
```

Ideally you should structure your XML something like:

```
<books>
  <book>
     <abc><fm>text</fm></abc>
     <def></def>
     <ghi></ghi>
  </book>
  <book>
     <abc><fm>text</fm></abc>
     <def></def>
     <ghi></ghi>
   </book>
   <book>
      <abc><fm>text</fm></abc>
      <def></def>
      <ghi></ghi>
   </book>
</books>
```

Comment: i am looping through the nodes , and passing the node and expression what u r saying will work for document, Not for node